# VHDL Synthesis Warnings

Tags: fpga, vhdl, synthesis, vivado

I have a question about warning messages from Vivado synthesis tools in VHDL source files. I know for a proper answer I should be providing more information, so I would appreciate just letting me know if this message is what I expect the error to be.

I have components that are 32 bit in size, and are nested inside other components.

I am assuming this error means that I am driving this pin from more than one place at one time in my project? I am using signals inside these components, so maybe they are being multi-driven, or is this to do with the hardware buffers the hardware synthesis tools are generating?.

Below is the warning messages I have in question:

[image: Vivado Synthesis Warning Message]

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. Perhaps it hasn't been tested thoroughly enough in simulation? That is usually where these issues are picked up.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks Brian, yeah you were correct. I have provided my own answer to this question to close it off.

Answer (score 4):

As BrianDrummond pointed out in the comment section, I was driving the same pins in my source file multiple times. Although this is only in simulation as it is during the test phase, and not on a FPGA board, I am relatively new to FPGAs / VHDL.

I have around 15 instances of the same component in my top level file and I copy and pasted each instance declaration in the top level file to save time.

However I forgot to change the output signal assignment so the last 3 component instances were trying to drive one signal vector at the same time.

I changed the component output signals to unique vectors and the warning messages are gone.

Thanks Brian for your help!

Comment: Beginners tip: Always treat critical warnings like errors. Never disregard them.

Comment: @MituRaj Yeah. Out of curiosity, what would of happened if I tried to map this logic onto real FPGA hardware? Would it let me implement of the board, or would the behaviour just be erratic?

Comment: It will be captured as DRC error during bitstream generation, if I remember well. So you can't burn it into FPGA as bitstream cannot be generated.

Comment: @MituRaj Ah ok, good to know. I hope however I never experience it haha!